# Sum and average of multiple object elements inside an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, object, sum, average

I am trying to send a response from Django to the frontend where my response looks like this

```
[
        {
            "MonthNameOfYear": "January",
            "Population": 113692,
            "Density": 68247,
        },
        {
            "MonthNameOfYear": "February",
            "Population": 973990,
            "Density": 58158,
        }
        {
            "MonthNameOfYear": "March",
            "Population": 534123,
            "Density": 33242,
        }
        {
            "MonthNameOfYear": "April",
            "Population": 234520,
            "Density": 12340,
        }
        {
            "MonthNameOfYear": "May",
            "Population": 153234,
            "Density": 42342,
        }
]
```

I want another array where I have sum of the population of all the months and average of density
Something like this

```
[
    { 
         "totalPopulation": something,
         "avgDensity": something
    }
]
```

The number of objects may vary. Plus the elements inside the objects may also increase for which I need to calculate the sum and average.
Right now I am hitting a database to fetch the data and making it an array, I don't want to change anything in that as it is a common function in lot of other cases.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a list of the desired entities from the list given (I suppose it is named `some_list`, as you do not provide a name):

```
population_list = [d['Population'] for d in some_list]
```

You can calulate the total population by simply summing the list:

```
total_population = sum(population_list)
```

For calculation of average so many possible solution exist, that it is almost impossible to name all of them. On possiblity might be `mean()` from the `statistics` package